Reporting significance of fixed effects in clmms - when to use ANODE tables?
I am working on some mixed effects models for ordinal outcomes using clmm. I have settled on my final model, and now want to present the findings. On reading around, I see the use of ANODE tables both in model comparison and to break down the contribution of each fixed effects in the model. I am not able to find any guidance on whether this is relevant for reporting, and what best practice might be. The model is estimated using ordinal package in R and the ANODE table is from RVAideMemoire.
In the event, there is very little difference in the findings between this and the z-tests reported in the model output (shown below). However, I would like to understand more about what the differences are between the two sets of output. Can anyone suggest some pointers? I can find information about model comparisons, but not answers to my specific query about how to report on the significance of fixed effects in the final model.
Many thanks!
        Estimate     Error     z      Pr(>|z|)
            
Var1     -2.966      0.482    -6.152  <0.001
Var2     -2.102      0.486    -4.32   <0.001
Var3     -1.593      0.476    -3.349   0.001
Var4      0.973      0.474     2.051   0.040
Var5     -0.711      0.175     -4.07  <0.001


Analysis of Deviance (Type II test)

     LR Chisq   Df     Pr(>Chisq)   
Var1 29.2981    1      <0.001   ***
Var2 16.2687    1      <0.001   ***
Var3 10.2870    1       0.001   **
Var4 3.9415     1       0.047   *
Var5 14.5733    1      <0.001   ***

